# Any trick to make get-pip.py install a specific pip version?

Tags: python, pip

PIP was recently (yesterday) upgraded from 1.5.6 to 6.0.1. It broke a couple of my stuff.
I'm looking for a way to make the "get-pip.py" script install 1.5.6 instead of the latest version.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x? Also, are you using virtualenv or just installing locally?

Comment: `get-pip.py` is a script to bootstrap `pip` if it is not present. Once you have an arbitrary `pip` version, you should be able to up/downgrade it with `pip install pip==1.5.6`

Comment: @ham-sandwich python2.7, locally.
@cel I'm aware installing an older version right after `get-pip.py` is possible. I'm looking for a way to install the old version right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're running your script, but you should be able to pull off something like:

```
python get-pip.py && pip install -I pip==1.5.6
```

You may need to prepend `sudo` to both commands.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption-I

Comment: I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve installing a new version and then downgrading. I'm aware this is possible, was looking for some other trick.

Comment: Note that this does NOT work if get-pip.py installs a version of pip that is incompatible with your system. For example, if you are running a (very old) Fedora 12 system, which runs Python 2.6.2, the most recent pip will fail to downgrade to the older pip, because it cannot actually install anything.

Answer (score 17):

This is a relatively old question, but I discovered today that recent versions of `get-pip.py` allow you to pass in an argument such as `pip<6` to ensure that the pip version installed is < 6:

```
[Nautilus@Nautilus scripts]$ python get-pip.py "pip<6"
Collecting pip<6
  Downloading pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.0MB 608kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-1.5.6
```

This seems to work with any argument form you could pass to pip itself, e.g. >, <, <=, >=, and ==

Comment: Thanks, this finally fixed my ubuntu 16.04 pip10 headache

Comment: This solution works in 2021. But Windows will not take a single quote, so you need to use double quotes, e.g. `python get-pip.py "pip<20"`.

Comment: Thanks for the note @bfris! Double quotes will work on *nix systems also, so I edited the answer to use them

Comment: two beers this gentleman, @MPlanchard. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad this old answer is still proving useful!

Answer (score 5):

As I tried to explain in the comments, `get-pip.py` in meant to be a bootstrapping method for `pip`. The problem it aims to solve is that you need `pip` to install `pip`.

The script does not allow the user to choose which version of `pip` you will get, it automatically downloads the latest version.

You can adapt the script and change

```
def bootstrap(tmpdir=None):
    # Import pip so we can use it to install pip and maybe setuptools too
    import pip

    # We always want to install pip
    packages = ["pip"]
```

to

```
def bootstrap(tmpdir=None):
    # Import pip so we can use it to install pip and maybe setuptools too
    import pip

    # We always want to install pip
    packages = ["pip==1.5.6"]
```

Now the script should always install `pip-1.5.6` instead of the latest version found on `pypi`.

Comment: Also, after reading the get-pip.py code, it won't work without an internet connection. It doesn't unpack the zip file at all. It extracts it to a temporary directory and adds it to `sys.path`, then, the `bootstrap` function imports it and calls pip.main() to install the pip package.

Comment: @omribahumi, I am very sorry - I really should have tested my suggestion. The thing about the included `binary` code is right for `ensurepip`, but not for `get-pip.py`. The edited version should really work now (This time I tested the code :))